# Are people downvoting too freely?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

To clarify, this question is **NOT** about the rep.  I'm **NOT** complaining about the downvotes.

For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077910/emulator-unable-to-connect-to-internet/4079670#4079670) answer works.  Solves the problem.  One glance at the link may seem like it's fixing another problem, but this works for the OP's problem too.  My concern is this: Working(correct) answers will become obscured because people glance at them once and downvote without even trying it.  Anyone else think this is a problem?

*Note:* The linked answer had a negative score when I linked it.

Comment: Where's the usual MSO sympathy voting? His answer is still -1. C'mon, where's that meta love?

Comment: Sorry, I just have to quote this from the comments in that answer: "my problem is that the internet itself isn't working"

Comment: dude, you are simply asking for it. lolz. welcome to mso. -1.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: and my answer fixes that.

Comment: @John the answer you link to has one downvote, and one upvote. Hardly good reference to illustrate the issue, is it?

Comment: @Pekka: The answer did not have an upvote when I linked it.  In answer, not anymore it isn't.

Comment: @John - currently you only have one example on which to base your question. I'd like to see more examples before drawing a conclusion.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 - that was a *joke*, it ends with a smiley.

Comment: @Mark - I know, but it's a lot funnier taken out of context.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 - =:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can understand this. You're saying that the answer really is appropriate? Because to me, reading it, it seems to be completely un-related to the question. It needs to be better phrased, clearly stating that this will fix the OP's problem, even though it seems unrelated.

All that said, that question should have been moved to one of the SE sites anyway.

Comment: Yes!  It **IS** appropriate!  As you demonstrated, people just glance at it without trying it.  Anyone who tried it would have found out it worked.

Comment: @John - we don't all have the time to test every single response on the site, and frankly 99% of the time if it looks irrelevant, it usually is. You need to make it very, very clear that even though the link LOOKS irrelevant, it really isn't.

Comment: yes, @john, you need to work on your presentation. don't expect people to spend time trying to figure out what you mean. take the time to spell it out. And complaining about downvotes is the quickest way to get more of them. ;-)

Comment: @Farseeker: Point taken.  I'll work on my presentation.

Comment: @Sky Sanders: I thought I had spelled it out.  And like I said, **I am not complaining about the downvotes!**

Comment: @John - I personally often down vote questions that use a link instead of putting the content into the answer. I do not find the answer useful (a downvote criterion) if I have to click on a link (which may or may not work). People should put the answer into the answer itself. (in this case, I voted to close and didn't down vote anything... (on SO ;) )).

Comment: And related to @Peter's comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @Peter: What was I supposed to do, download the files then upload them to my site?

Comment: @John - Copy paste them into your answer. There's no size limit, and if you paste it all into one code block, your answer won't take up that much space either, due to scrolling. Link rot is a real problem, and your answer becomes 100% worthless when that link dies, unless you put the information in your answer.

Comment: @Peter: I don't think you understand.  One was an image, and the other an archive.