# What is the reason for a user to downvote a well explained question?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

This morning I asked a question with a good explanation which I wrote after a long time of thinking.
A user has downvoted my question. I really wondered what could be the reason because I know what I asked for and that too was a critical question. And then I deleted that, but still I want to know what could be the reason. Aren't we here to ask questions? Can't the user vote to delete instead of downvote? I ask for a suggestion...

Comment: Can you show a link to the question in question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are people downvoting too freely?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69376/are-people-downvoting-too-freely)

Comment: -1: not explained well enough. (jk) Don't take downvotes to heart.

Comment: I thought of creating a new explanation to the question which was down voted 3 times and up voted one time and with 3 answers. If it was not a good question then how did i get three answers? anyway... i am following the below guidelines by various users.

Comment: So still: *which* question? (And please don't post the same comment multiple times. Thanks!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question [According to Yahoo recommendations, script links should be placed in the end of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415761/according-to-yahoo-recommendations-script-links-should-be-placed-in-the-end-of-t):

> Hi,
>
> When i was reading a blog i read about this comment by another user that
>
> **According to Yahoo! recommendations, script links should be placed in the end of the page**
>
> in this page
>
> http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/jquery-live-events#comment10
>
> If this is a duplicate entry then users shall vote to delete it. Else i expect users to discuss about it.
>
> I really want to know the reason. so this question. Your suggestions would be helpful for many users like me.
>
> Thank you.

I'd say:

- Remove the "Hi". (Note [the tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIYm3.jpg) that is shown on some pages. Do you [really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) want to use a whole line in that tooltip for a salutation?)
- The bolded *"According to Yahoo! recommendations [...]"* is a quote. Use `>` for quotes, not bold.
- Look up that Yahoo! recommendation and link to that, rather than asking the readers to read some comment on some web site.
- *"If this is a duplicate entry then users shall vote to delete it. Else i expect users to discuss about it."* annoys me *a lot*. It's *your* responsibility to ensure it's not a duplicate. No need to tell others how to use the site!
- Likewise *"I really want to know the reason. so this question. Your suggestions would be helpful for many users like me."* is just not needed. Everyone asks questions because they want an answer!
- Your title is a statement, not a question.

I'm sure you've given the above a lot of thought too. But I'd say the (duplicate) question would be a one-liner:

> Why does Yahoo! [recommend](http://example.org) to place script links at the end of the page?

Comment: Newlines are stripped for excerpts so "hi" would use 4 characters, including the comma, not a whole line.

Comment: @Kop, you're right, my bad. It's still taking a whole line (and an empty line) [in tooltips](http://i.imgur.com/SIYm3.jpg) though.

Comment: +1 Point 4 is key. "If this is a duplicate entry then users shall vote to delete it" kind of implies no work was done on the part of the OP before posting.

Comment: I thought of creating a new explanation to the question which was down voted 3 times and up voted one time and with 3 answers. If it was not a good question then how did i get three answers? anyway... i am following the guidelines posted for my question by various users.

Answer (score 3):

Don't take down votes to personally. One vote could have been an accident.  He/she might have thought they clicked the up vote.  I would have left your question up in the hope that if there truly was a problem that someone else would add a comment explaining why there was a problem with it.

Comment: `<ianfleming>` Once is happenstance. Twice is coincidence. Three times is enemy action. `</ianfleming>` ;)

Comment: Yes. in one day i got 9 points down votes. When i got it for the first time 3 months ago i did not mind because i did not analyze what i asked but now it was different. that is the reason i asked as question.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed in your questions that you often format your question with one paragraph per sentence. Maybe downvoters don't even bother reading it and assume just from the formatting that it is a bad question. I don't approve of that, I'm just saying that if this happens or has happened more than this one time you might try to trust word wrapping a bit more or use bullets/numbering to outline important points.

I'm the first one not to care about formatting. But it would be a shame to see a perfectly good question ignored or downvoted because it "didn't look pretty".

EDIT:
There is more than one level of formatting quality:

1. So bad that it can be hardly read.
2. Nice. Not that bad so that people would avoid it. In these examples, just using word wrapping would make it into this category.
3. Pretty! If you use things like numbering, bullets, kbd tags (where needed). This is good in that it not just doesn't make people ignore it (or downvote). It actually keeps attention because it's easy to read.

Now, in my last sentence before edit I when I said "pretty" I meant "that which falls in category 3". Post being *pretty* in this sense is a very useful thing.

Comment: I agree with this being a possible reason. The formatting like this makes it hard to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202060/reloading-page-while-an-ajax-request-in-progress-gives-empty-response-and-status

Comment: Formatting is more than about looking pretty.  Poor formatting affects readability and places a burden on the reader to extract information. A poorly formatted question is worth less to the site, and to the OP, as many people will simply move on if the question is too hard to read.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I meant *pretty* in a more general sense, which includes what you said. See my edit. And thanks for pointing that out, it did look ambiguous as it was.

Comment: Almost revoked my upvote. `<kbd>` is ugly!

Comment: @Arjan: On SO, <kbd> is not that useful (as opposed to code formatting). But on SU or AskUbuntu, if someone asks something like: "What is the keyboard shortcut for X on Y?" this feature can be really useful because it increases visibility of actual keys even if they are within text. However, I am not defending abuse of <kbd> nor this particular look-and-feel they have now.

Comment: Luckily comments do not support `<kbd>`, but I really find Ctrl-X easier to read than [the thing outputted](http://i.imgur.com/Xtlc9.png) for `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>`...

Comment: @Arjan: After comparing them side by side I am inclined to agree. Maybe, it's because as programmers we prefer plain text. It would be interesting to do a survey to see what do non-programmer users think about it as opposed to programmers. Or maybe it was done already